# Find element's onclick event with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, onclick, attr

I need to clone the onclick event of an element from one link to another.

```
<a id='foo' onclick='bar'>
```

I need some javascript or jquery that will return `bar'.

```
$('#foo').attr('onclick')
    //returns 'undefined'
```

Comment: I get the full function returned as a string, not `undefined`: http://jsfiddle.net/Z4gAp/. What browser are you using? (I'm using Chrome on a Mac)

Comment: This works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/73yns/

@Clive: Mine works just fine, it returns "bar."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the native `.getAttribute` method of the DOM element.

I have compared `.attr('onclick')` to `[0].getAttribute('onclick')`:

- The jQuery method returned `function onclick(event) {bar;}` (jQuery version 1.5.2, included by Stack Overflow)
- The JavaScript method returned `"bar"`

Test case (copy & paste in console):

```
$('<a id="foo" onclick="bar">')[0].getAttribute('onclick')
```

Comment: Really? Both methods gives me `bar`

Comment: @JohnGiotta I tested the code in a console at Stack Overflow, which includes jQuery version 1.5.2 (Get version using `$().jquery`). See also, this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3qkJr/

Answer (score 1):

It returns bar just fine in jQuery 1.6.4, where the prop method returns the full function instead. Solution would be to upgrade your jQuery to the newest version.

http://jsfiddle.net/n9UdN/